# Google Hangouts vibrates although vibration is disabled

Tags: sms, notifications, vibration, google-hangouts, moto-x

I'm having a really annoying issue to where when i receive a text message through hangouts my phone will vibrate and make a sound when it isn't muted even though in the hangouts app and in the settings on the phone, I have vibrate unchecked. Am I missing some option? I haven't modified android on anyway on this phone.

Comment: There is a seperate vibrate option for SMS in Hangouts, that may be it. Also, if your phone is set to vibrate in general, Hangouts may default to 'System Setting' rather than its own individual one. It's annoying.

Comment: This is happening to me as well with the most recent update to Hangouts (12/11/2014). Unchecking vibrate in the settings has no effect.

Comment: Possible answer [Globally Disable Vibration](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/91475/globally-disable-vibration)

Comment: Same problem here, no working solution found :-/.

Comment: It seems to be a known bug: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/hangouts/PJPTKjqVyg0

Comment: Here is the solution : http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/135591/how-to-turn-off-vibration-in-google-hangouts-version-6-1-109448852

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Hangouts and make sure you're on the conversation list page.

Choose the menu dots in the upper right and choose "Settings -> SMS" and there should be a check box a few spaces down for "Vibrate" under "Notifications"

Let us know if that works!

[image]

<sup>(Click on the image for larger version)</sup>

Comment: this does not work. i have all the vibrate options set to off in hangouts but my phone will still vibrate for SMS messages, but not for google messages.