# Globally disable vibration?

Tags: vibration, htc-one-m8

Is there a way to disable vibration on HTC One M8 regardless of individual application settings?

I can't conceive of a situation in which I would ever want my phone to vibrate so I'd just assume kill it at the source, if possible. If no soft solution exists I may need to resort to ripping the motor out.

To any hardware engineers out there - build a phone without vibration and I'd buy it in an instant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Sure!

Though a rooted device is needed, and in the case of HTC phones, probably also s-off. Just download [VibraFix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cynyx.vibrafix), which will allow you to completely turn off vibration. It will also allow you to pass through calls and texts, if that is needed.

Answer (score 2):

I've made an app that can disable/enable vibrations system-wide because Android lacks such option for inexplicable reasons - [Global Vibration Toggle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sk.blade.globalvibratetoggle).

It requires a rooted phone as well and has a widget toggle and an automatic mode.