# How to turn off Vibration in Google Hangouts [ Version: 6.1.109448852]

Tags: notifications, 6.0-marshmallow, google-hangouts, vibration

It is really annoying that the mobile phone vibrates on every message arrives on google hangouts after update, how to disable it ? I mean for all messages I just don't need vibration, only sound notification is required.

Comment: related http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/59046/google-hangouts-vibrates-although-vibration-is-disabled

Answer (score 12):

I found my own solution to it. Here are the instructions:

1. Open hangouts. Click on the menu (three lines on top left corner of hangouts).

   <sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

   [image: IMG:]
2. Click on settings.  Click on your email account, on which you want to control notifications
   .
3. Click on Notification under the given options.
4. Uncheck the sound or vibrate option to disable/enable them.

   <sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

   [image: IMG:]